# Javascript : Working with a large JSON object / string in URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, url

I have quite a specific demand, and I wonder if this is even possible.

I am writing a client-side application in Javascript / jQuery, but I can't store anything. I'm using an external library which needs a Javascript object as an initial parameter, and this object can be quite large (at least more than 6000 characters, it could be way more than that). I would like to be able to "share" this Object through the URL, so any client could rebuild the application with a specific configuration object. The URL would be ugly but I could live with that I guess, the main problem is the maximum characters an URL can contain in IE (11+) : ~2000. Apparently other main browsers can take a very long hash without any problem.

At first, I searched around string compression libraries (lzw, pako...), and while those libraries often do a great job for short strings, those can't help me with the huge JSON I need to share.

I'm open to any suggestions. If there is any other way than passing it through the URL, I would be interested, but I'm afraid without the ability to store anything server-side, there is not.

Comment: Why you don't use post method?

Comment: Store data in some kind of database. In URL share only the token needed to access data in the database.

Comment: If you are force to do it so you can separate your string into array which each element of it has maximum 2000 characters. Then post each of them in individual url. Also you can use a key for detecting order of them in server side

Comment: I can't use a database. The point is to share the entire object from a client to a client, this is why I lean towards the URL, so it doesn't really share anything, the application just rebuilds with the JSON / object / string whatever it is in the hash of the URL.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the:

```
window.location.hash
```

Worked well on updated Safari, Firefox & Chrome: URL lenth of 60000+ was tolerated...

```
yoururl.com/#yourverylongstring
```

Comment: That was the original idea, but unfortunately IE has a ~2000 characters limit